# Command to see serial port properties

Tags: raspbian

I am looking for RP command to display the serial port properties, in windows this is done using mode command as per this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690073/serial-com-port-timeout-setting

How to see the same in linux/Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stty` command.

`man stty` for details.